# How to make ui-router always start in a given state

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angular-ui-router

I have two states, `preloader` and `game`. I want to *always* start off in the `preloader` state, which will then pass over to `game` once my assets are loaded.

However, my problem is that if I define the preloader url to be `/preloader`, and the game url to be `/game`, then when the user reloads the page on `/game`, they will be routed to my `game` state, and will *not* see my preloader.

How can I configure angular ui-router to achieve the behavior I want?

Comment: what you have tried so far?

Comment: so far I've tried putting a run block to run `$state.go('preloader')` when the app starts, but evidently the actual URL setting overrides this.

Comment: figured it out, posting a solution

Answer (score 1):

You can set the URL that ui-router reads before the app even loads using `$location`:

```
.run(function($location) {
  $location.path('/preloader');
})
```

Answer (score 0):

You could watch every state change with an interceptor.

```
$rootScope.$on('$stateChangeStart', function (event,next, nextParams, fromState) {   
  event.preventDefault();
  $state.go('preloader', {}, {reload: true});        
});
```

That would prevent default behavior and do whatever checking you need to do before redirecting.